# ¿Cómo ocultar div para mostrar otro sucesivamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

he intentado hacer una función en jquery o javascript que pueda ocultar divs para mostrar otros de forma dinámica sin repetir el mismo código javascript, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Sólo pude hacer una función básica que oculta y muestra divs limitadamente, no es lo que deseo pero es un avance.

```
  function ChangePage($a, $b){
  var a = $('#'+$a);
  var b = $('#'+$b);
  a.hide();
  b.show();
}
```

Esto es una vista previa de lo que me refiero con exacitud
https://gyazo.com/149a28082159d5bc3938c20292f4a527

Answer (score 0):

Para eso no es necesario usar jquery lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```
function ChangePage($a,$b){
 setInterval(function(){
var a=document.querySelector("#"+$a); 
 var b=document.querySelector("#"+$b);
 if(a.style.display != "none"){
 a.style.display="none"; b.style.display="block";
  }else{
  b.style.display="none"; a.style.display="block";
  }
 },1000);
 }
```

Aqui lo que hice fue ver si ya estaba oculto y si no lo ocultaba. tambien hice que se ejecutara cada segundo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Referente a tu respuesta, no responde a mi pregunta, si no más bien extiende un poco más mi código base en mi publicación en jquery pasándolo a javascript neto.

Comment: podrias intentar entonces eliminar la funcion y dejar que corra solo directamente